# Spring REST API custom exceptions handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 3.2 application and I've created a REST API based on Spring MVC. I am using @ControllerAdvice annotation for custom exceptions handling. For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ResponseBody
    public ExceptionMessage handleMyCustomException(MyCustomException ex){
        return new ExceptionMessage(ex.getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage(), ex.getExceptionCode());
    }
}
```

The issue is that I see how my custom exception is thrown but the exception handler method is actually not being executed and hence my exception message is not returned to the client. Instead, I noticed in the logs how the DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handles the exception (with a Spring generic one, `ServletRequestBindingException` in a GET method). How can I get rid of this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the package of `RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler` listed in the `component-scan base-package`attribute?

Comment: @zeroflagL Yes, it is

Comment: Wait a minute, `ServletRequestBindingException`? Sounds like your exception is thrown before a handler method is called.

Comment: You were right @zeroflagL, I did not notice some request params were missing in my API calls testing process. If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it with pleasure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ServletRequestBindingException` is a hint that something went wrong before the handler method of the controller. In this case some binding issue.

Exception handlers annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` are only called when an exception is thrown within a controller handler method (`@RequestMapping`).

Comment: Is there any way to customize exception handling within automatically exposed spring-data-rest endpoints?